# JQuery - Show Additional Image on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, onmouseover, jquery-hover

I am practicing JS/JQuery and trying to create a sports web site that shows a small player image and a couple of stats next to it.  When this small image is rolled over, I want a different large image to appear to the right.

The images and player info are in a table.  Both images are within the table.  The image that I want to appear on hover is set to display:none.

I can make the images appear but they all appear in a stack when 1 thumbnail is hovered.

Here is a small sample of the HTML:

```
<table id="roster">
    <tr>
        <th class="title" colspan=4>St. Louis Blues 2013-2014 Roster</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="positions" colspan=2>Forwards</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Player</th>
        <th>Shoots</th>
        <th>Acquired</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="large" style="position:absolute;margin-left:550px;display:none;"><img src="images/backes_large.jpg" width="500px" /></span><span class="small"><img src="images/backes_small.png" alt="david backes" width="70px" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>David Backes "C"</td>
        <td>Right</td>
        <td>2003</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="large" style="position:absolute;margin-left:550px;display:none;"><img src="images/berglund_large.jpg" width="500px" /></span><span class="small"><img src="images/berglund_small.png" alt="patrik berglund" width="70px" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>Patrik Berglund</td>
        <td>Left</td>
        <td>2006</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The script is:

```
$('span.small').hover(
    function () {

        $('span.large').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('span.large').hide;
    });
});
```

Obviously I want to open the additional image that is only in that table row.  This is where I am stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can u show us a js fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them will appear because you're using `span.large` and there are multiple of them. Instead use `$(this).prev()` for the related span to hide/show.

```
$('span.small').hover(
    function () { 
        $(this).prev('span.large').show();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).prev('span.large').hide();
    });
});
```

Also, you're missing the parentheses `()` in the last line

Comment: @user2941938 - glad to help. also upvote helpful answers.(shameless, aren't I :))